# Update Rows in google spreadsheets with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, spreadsheet

im using google spreadsheets as means of recording timestamp. im using [farinspace googlespreadsheet php](https://github.com/farinspace/google-spreadsheet/downloads) and zendgdata. i can add new rows with no problem , but i just found myself in a problem...

what happens if i want to updateRow, where column name is equal to todays day,,,in other words i want to update the timestamp today, being monday,,,and when i do, all rows with value Monday on the Day column gets timestamp...

i just need to do it on one row, and keep track of what row i am so i can consecutively update next days... i hope all that makes sense... if it doesnt please let me know so i can explain my self better.

```
include_once("Google_Spreadsheet.php");
$u = "dude@gmail.com";
$p = "dudepass";
$ss = new Google_Spreadsheet($u,$p);
$ss->useSpreadsheet($id_employee);
$id = date('l'); //this gives me todays day name
$row = array
    (
         "In" => date("H:i")
    ); // using this in column In, i will post date


   if ($ss->updateRow($row,"day=".$id))
    {
        echo "Updated";
    }else{
        echo "Some Error";
    }
```

that above is the basic function of the link above of farinspace sheet, the updateRow, loops through all rows that have the "monday" name and timestamps all of them. i need to know how can i prevent that...saying for example, today being monday update only "In" and "Out" columns of row monday,,, not all rows having monday in it

```
    function updateRow($row,$search)
{
    if ($this->client instanceof Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets AND $search)
    {
        $feed = $this->findRows($search);

        if ($feed->entries)
        {
            foreach($feed->entries as $entry) 
            {
                if ($entry instanceof Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListEntry)
                {
                    $update_row = array();

                    $customRow = $entry->getCustom();
                    foreach ($customRow as $customCol) 
                    {
                        $update_row[$customCol->getColumnName()] = $customCol->getText();
                    }

                    // overwrite with new values
                    foreach ($row as $k => $v) 
                    {
                        $update_row[$this->cleanKey($k)] = $v;
                    }

                    // update row data, then save
                    $entry = $this->client->updateRow($entry,$update_row);
                    if ( ! ($entry instanceof Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListEntry)) return FALSE;
                }
            }

            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

that is the updateRow function

Comment: You might want to add at least a few lines of code illustrating your problem.

Comment: yep was into that just now